Junit DisplayNameGenerator with property file, in a spring boot
I was doing by tests like this
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGeneration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.ReplaceUnderscores.class)
public class AddressViewTest {

@Nested
    class contains_hidden_field {
....

Which is  working great for me, underscore in the name of the test are replaced with spaces.
Then I've found out that there is a way with jupiter to configure it once, and never doing it in the next test class.
Like so: https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-display-name-generator-default
So I've created the following file with the project path src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties
junit.jupiter.displayname.generator.default=org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayNameGenerator$ReplaceUnderscores

But then the test report shows underscore now I assume the file is ignored.
I'm using maven with a spring boot 3 project if it helps.

Is the file really in src/test/resources and is the name correct?

I added this to src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties, and it's working here.

Don't know what changed, but after starting a fresh compile, everything seam to work as expected
